# How to create a JavaScript Library

Tags: javascript, npm, package, node-modules, npm-publish

I've created some functions in JavaScript.

I've found out that I reuse them in many projects.

So I decided to create a small JavaScript Library for my coding.
A Library like react, react-dom, jquery which I can install with npm:
`npm install <my-personal-library>`

I searched the net. I learned that I can use `npm publish <my-personal-library`, but I do not know how to format my library and functions to use and install them like an npm package.

Also, I have no idea about creating type definitions for my functions and library.
like @types/react
Any guidence?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry

Answer (score 1):

- To install your package in a pc you have to set up a cli package inside npm module.

  ```
    import { Command } from "commander";
    import open from "open";

    // [] indicates that this is optional
    // <> indicates that this is a required value
    export const serveCommand = new Command()
      .command("serve [filename]")
      // when user enters node index.js --help, it sees description
      .description("ADd a description")
      .option("-p, --port <number>", "port to run server on", "4005")
      .option("-v, --version", "show version", version, "")
      // first arg will be the arg that passed in command() SO filename
      // second arg is all other options
      //  THIS IS WE TELL WHAT TO DO
      .action(async (filename = "main.js", options: { port: string }) => {
        try {
          // this is where you add logic about what to do when enterd the command
          open("http://localhost:4005");
        } catch (error: any) {
          if (error.code === "EADDRINUSE") {
            console.error("Port is in use. Try runnng on a different port ");
          } else {
            console.log("Issue is :", error.message);
          }
          process.exit(1);
        }
      });
  ```
- To make cli run the code, in your main file

  ```
  //whenever anyone runs cli from command line, this file will be executed.
  !/usr/bin/env node
  import { program } from "commander";
  // this is the above command
  import { serveCommand } from "./commands/serve";

  // you could chain other commands .addCommand(otherCommand)
  program.addCommand(serveCommand);

  // parse this and run the aprropriate command that you put together
  program.parse(process.argv);
  ```
- as you see you might have different sub packages and each sub packages will have their own `package.json`. To communicate between those sub packages, you add them in their dependencies inside package.json. for example, you have to use cli package inside your main package. so in package.json

  ```
   "dependencies": {
      "@my-npm-package/cli": "^1.0.15",
       // other dependencies
      "express": "^4.17.1",
    }
  ```
- Since you have different sub packages and you have to group them together.  Assgin those pacakges into an "organization". another term is to "create scoped package". "@types/cors" and "@types/express" are scoped packages.

##### Declaring Scoped Packages

- in npm page, on the right, cick on "Add organization"
- organization name should be unique
- update name of the dependencies in package.json of each package.
- Manage packages

Use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage all of those npm packages. it is for managing multi project packages. - Lerna is one tool out there in the wild that we can use for managing a multi package project. Yarn and Npm are similar to lerna. there are also Bolt and Luigi.

Answer (score 0):

**About how to publish your library**

You can read the official npm documentation on how to create nodejs package modules:
https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules

Basically, what you need is a JS module file (IE `test.js`) to be exported with `exports` keyword like:

```
exports.printMsg = function() {
  console.log("This is a message from the demo package");
}
```

Then publish the module with `npm publish` (add `--access public` if you want it to be public)
Finally import the package in the project you need it with `npm install <your-module-name>`

**About the type definitions**

I understand that you are using typescript? Then the following link is a good read:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend checking out 'jslib-base' for developing JS libraries (https://github.com/yanhaijing/jslib-base).  It’s a useful scaffold to simplify your JS library development process!